# SQL change the "enter value" text to something else?

Tags: sqlplus

I am inputting a value into sql plus, and here is how I am getting the input:

`And Abc.Abdef = &Abcdef;`

When I execute it, it says:

`Enter value for Abcdef:`

How can I change the text `enter value for` to something else?

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible. SQL*Plus doesn't let you customise the prompt for substitution variables.

However, [you can prompt for an input (with a custom prompt)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve005.htm#SQPUG026) and assign that to a variable which you then use in your statement:

```sql
SQL> accept foo prompt 'FOO: '
FOO: bar
SQL> select * from dual where '&foo'='bar';
old   1: select * from dual where '&foo'='bar'
new   1: select * from dual where 'bar'='bar'

D
-
X
```

Comment: is there a way i can add some text? for example i want it to say something like "enter values for Abcdef, between 1 and 10: